# Headless Chrome erroring out in PM2

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, pm2, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to do something like similar to what is explained in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf-chrome).
It basically tries to launch a chrome browser instance running in [headless mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

But the process errors out as soon as it is launched. When the same command is executed directly from the command prompt, it runs well.

The command I have used is

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

The PM2 Config Json is below

```
{
"apps":
    [{
    "name":"google-chrome-headless",
    "script":"google-chrome",
    "watch":true,
    "args":"--headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu"
    }]
}
```

The above configuration did not start the headless browser. It failed.

I tried to put the command and the args in a shell script and tried to execute it. It still failed.

```
{
"apps":
    [{
    "name":"google-chrome-headless",
    "script":"launchchrome.sh",
    "watch":true
    }]
}
```

The PM2 log or report doesn't give any useful information. Chrome log gives an error like

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

which is again not very useful (because no page was launched in chrome)

Can someone help me in getting this running?

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit.

Comment: If you don't want to run pm2 with node, then you need to use the --interpreter, maybe bash will do for your shell script. It's trying to start your script (launchchrom.sh) with node, that's why you get that error.

Comment: @ippi Thanks for the tip. I used exec_interpreter option in the config json and it worked.

Comment: This is the final one that worked

{
"apps":
    [{
    "name":"google-chrome-headless",
    "script":"launchchrome.sh",
    "watch":true,
    "exec_interpreter": "bash"
    }]
}